# Delaying sending of mail until transaction commits

Tags: java, spring, email, transactions, xa

Does anyone have a good tutorial or some advice on how to implement one's own XAResource? I need Spring's MailSender to be transactional, so that the mail will only be sent once the transaction commits, and it seems there isn't any existing transactional wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to wait for the commit, as you say in a comment, you can investigate using [`TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#registerSynchronization%28org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronization%29) to trigger email sending on commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization` (like *gpeche* mentioned) with a `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` which has a variety of methods that are called at various stages of the current transaction. I think the most suitable method for the question is the [afterCommit](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html#afterCommit--).

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void afterCommit() {
        super.afterCommit();
        sendEmail();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, avoid code only answers. Put at least an explanation about the code you just added. It will help other users understand what was done.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some explanation and a javadoc link.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it's possible to implement true XAResource for SMTP. There should be transaction support on the resource manager (SMTP server in this case) and I don't believe there are any. I would say your best bet is 'Last resource commit' pattern - which allows one non XA resource participate in XA transaction. Search Google, there are plenty of info. Most Java EE servers supports this.

Comment: I agree, two phase commit is probably out of the question, so all I need is for the send action to wait for the commit. Seems this is exactly what 'Last resource commit' does, thanks. However, although there are lots of resources explaining what 'Last resource commit' is, I still have to find an explanation of how to implement it. Would I still implement a XAResource?

Answer (score 1):

One other option next to the one mentioned by gpeche, is sending a transactional JMS message from within the transaction. Then let the message listener (like e.g. a MDB bean) send the email.

Another trick in EJB is scheduling a timer from within a transaction. The timer is also transactional and will only be started when the transaction commits. Simply use a timer with timeout = 0, so it will start immediately after the transaction commits.